# Is it possible to create a to create a homemade weapon using electromagnetic or microwave energy, sound or sonic beams?

Tags: technology, warfare

Entire question:  is it possible to create a homemade weapon using electromagnetic, microwave energy and/or sound or sonic beams that can permeate buildings and their structure without damaging the buildings … BUT cause significant harm to who they’re targeting.  Do these weapons already exist?  Is there a record of these being used during a time of peace, in a non-war setting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/57788/a-handheld-microwave-gun-is-it-feasible-and-what-would-it-do .

Comment: technically a bomb is a sonic weapon.

Comment: @John - but typically doesn't harm humans but leave buildings standing. :D

Comment: @jdunlop nor will anything listed.

Comment: @John - as detailed in my answer, "electromagnetic" gives you a lot of leeway.  If you were to bathe a building in ionizing radiation, it would probably be bad for the occupants but not visibly damage the building.  Hard to make something that does that at home, though.

Comment: This is the sort of question that gets people on watch lists, especially since it lacks any worldbuilding context and the last subquestion is specifically asking for real-world history.

Comment: (a) If you take a moment to read the wikis for the tags you used, you will note that [tag:science-fiction], [tag:science-based], and [tag:hard-science] are all *mutually exclusive.* Without knowing more about what you're trying to achieve, I can't tell which one tag you should have - but I'm sure it's not [tag:hard-science]. Therefore, I've elected to remove them all. If you choose to add any back, remember you can choose only one. (b) If you read the [help], you'll learn that we allow one and only one question per post. (c) This appears to be a Real World research question (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... and not a question about an imaginary world, as required by the [help/on-topic]. We do allow quesitons about the Real World, but the context of the imaginary world is expected. (d) Questions asking for real data about deadly weapons are not prohibited, but we do expect to know more about why you're asking. (See [my answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8329/40609) to [How should we handle possibly legally/morally sensitive topics?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8322/40609). (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Finally, (e) you should understand that our focus is to help people develop and consistently use rules for an imaginary world of their own creation. Even when asking within that scope, the Book Rule (see [help/dont-ask] precludes lengthy, very detailed answers. Thus, you should expect to receive generalized information. (See [Advice concerning questions asking HOW to implement a technological procedure or device](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8273/40609).

Answer (score 2):

## Mostly No

The "mostly" is because "electromagnetic" casts a wide net.  Gamma rays can penetrate many substances without doing visible damage, but nevertheless will do bad things to living beings.  It stretches "homemade", but [The Nuclear Boy Scout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hahn) (David Hahn) made a substantial radiation source in his backyard by collecting a lot of old smoke detectors.  Creating such a radiation source would not do any damage to mundane objects, but would definitely be detrimental to those exposed.

Lasers can penetrate windows without harming them, and can blind a resident of the building with an eye-strike, but I doubt that's the kind of EM weapon of which you're thinking.

Microwave radiation (also covered under "electromagnetic radiation") is generally not harmful to people unless at extremely high intensities, and is blocked by just about anything (which is why microwave ovens work; if material didn't absorb the energy, food wouldn't heat in them).  Directing high-energy microwaves at the outside of a building would heat the outside of the building.

Sound is vibrations.  If you're projecting enough energy in vibrations to harm a person, it will also harm other objects around them.  You *could* presumably play a loud noise continuously outside of someone's domicile and deny them sleep, which is a harm that wouldn't affect the building itself.

Answer (score 1):

With current technology? No, not homemade and not one that's effective...

However - The history of home-made arms is an interesting one.

There's some extremely crude 3rd world home-made firearms which are single-shot and borderline useless/handgrenades.

But on the flipside there are things like the PA Luty Sub-machine gun, the australian Owen gun (which was first designed in a Shed IIRC), the Accuracy International L96 Rifle (which humorously was designed in a Shed, admittedly by skilled experts - to which the MoD sent out someone to confirm it wasn't just a couple of blokes in a Shed... Which it was... so they had to fool them)

TL;DR - if the technology is available to hobbyists, then it's not outside the realms of possibility that one could make a functioning home-made weapon.

E.G - a Hobbyist machinest with a Lathe, Mill and a few other tools (which doesn't have an unreasonable setup cost) can (and indeed, has) built functioning firearms.

So - looping back to your question - assume a little bit in the future where such EM technology is commonplace, then it's plausible.

As in - when Computers first came out they were the size of a room and used exclusively by Military, Government and Big business. Now we have things like Raspberry PI and a myriad of (relatively) simple coding tools.

Since you didn't define a Tech Level - if you make your world so that the usage of EM radiation is commonplace and easily available and there are hobbyist EM tinkerers - then it's **plausible** someone could make a homemade weapon.

Comment: Again, "EM" is not special.  I could make a homemade "EM" weapon by extracting the laser from a remaindered barcode scanner and removing the eye-safety measures.  The issue is that most electromagnetic radiation is either capable of passing through building structures and harmless (in that it also passes through the people, like radio), or incapable of passing through building structures and harmful (like a burning laser).

Answer (score 1):

### EM weapons? No. But you are not without options...

Others have already said you cant to it with EM weapons which I am inclined to agree with, but there are non-EM weapons that can generally meet your goals.

There are plenty of deadly gases you can make from consumer products that can be vented into a building. Maybe not as fancy as actually shooting through walls, but a tried and true way of harming everyone in an enclosed space without damaging the building.